# Access output of sbt print in Github Actions workflow

Tags: sbt, github-actions

I'm trying to save the output of running `sbt print version | tail -n 1` to an environment variable in a Github Actions workflow, and it doesn't seem to work.

This is what I think should work, but it's just an empty string, when I try to access the variable later on in the job:

`echo "TAG_VERSION=$(sbt 'print version' | tail -n 1)" >> $GITHUB_ENV`

It works great in my own shell, but not in Github Actions.

I'm using version `1.5.3`for `sbt`.

This is the logs for the step that doesn't seem to work, `test version` step, it just seems to not load up correctly.:

```
Run echo "TAG_VERSION=$(sbt 'print version' | tail -n 1)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  echo "TAG_VERSION=$(sbt 'print version' | tail -n 1)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    CI: true
    JAVA_HOME: /home/runner/.jabba/jdk/adopt@1.8.0-292
Downloading sbt launcher for 1.5.3:
  From  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt-launch/1.5.3/sbt-launch-1.5.3.jar
    To  /home/runner/.sbt/launchers/1.5.3/sbt-launch.jar
Downloading sbt launcher 1.5.3 md5 hash:
  From  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt-launch/1.5.3/sbt-launch-1.5.3.jar.md5
    To  /home/runner/.sbt/launchers/1.5.3/sbt-launch.jar.md5
[info] [launcher] getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.5.3  (this may take some time)...
[info] [launcher] getting Scala 2.12.14 (for sbt)...
```

This is the full workflow:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: olafurpg/setup-scala@v11
      #- name: run tests
       # run: |
        #  sbt test
      - name: docker login
        run: echo ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }} | docker login -u ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }} --password-stdin
      #- name: build image and publish
      #  run: sbt 'Docker / publish'
      - name: test version
        run: echo "TAG_VERSION=$(sbt 'print version' | tail -n 1)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: print test version
        run: echo ${{ env.TAG_VERSION }}
      - name: get version
        run: echo "TAG_VERSION=$(echo $(sbt -Dsbt.supershell=false 'print version' | tail -n 1))" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: checkout helm repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: peterstorm/dialer-integration-argo
          token: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          path: './dialer-integration-argo'
      - name: change image tag in helm repo
        uses: mikefarah/yq@master
        with:
          cmd: yq eval -i '.image.tag = "${{ env.TAG_VERSION }}"' './dialer-integration-argo/values.yaml'
      - name: push helm repo changes
        run: |
          cd dialer-integration-argo &&
          git config --global user.name 'Peter Storm' &&
          git config --global user.email 'peter.storm@peterstorm.io' &&
          git add . &&
          git commit -m "commit from github actions" &&
          git push origin master
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try debugging the GitHub action by printing the output of `sbt 'print version'`?

Comment: Why don't you `GITHUB_ENV="TAG_VERSION=$(sbt 'print version' | tail -n 1)"`? I thought `>>` would save the output of `echo` to a file pointed by `GITHUB_ENV`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski this part is correct. this is how one [adds environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) in GitHub Actions

Comment: Please, add sbt version (`project/build.properties`) and the relevant parts of the workflow YAML to the question. In particular, the setup steps. This behavior might depend on which sbt launcher you are using.

Comment: @laughedelic sbt version is 1.5.3 and at the moment I'm just trying to echo the output of the environment variable with `echo ${{ env.TAG_VERSION }}` in the next workflow step. And this is the output of the step:
```
From  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt-launch/1.5.3/sbt-launch-1.5.3.jar To  ...
Downloading sbt launcher 1.5.3 md5 hash:
  From  ..
    To  /home/runner/.sbt/launchers/1.5.3/sbt-launch.jar.md5
[info] [launcher] getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.5.3  (this may take some time)...
[info] [launcher] getting Scala 2.12.14 (for sbt)...
```

Comment: Please, add this to the question. These comments are not meant for blocks of code and extensive details. And add the exact steps of your workflow.

Comment: @laughedelic Done, apologies :)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, someone else finds this to be helpful (I know the question is over a year-old, but you never know). I had very similar issue, and was attempting to output the result of `$(sbt 'print version' | tail -n 1)` to a gha step output or the `$GITHUB_ENV`. After many different permutations I found success by setting the `-no-colors` flag on the sbt command so:

```yaml
- name: Get Version
  id: version
  run: echo ::set-output name=snapshot::$(sbt -no-colors 'print version' | tail -n 1)
- name: Show Version
  run: echo $(sbt -no-colors 'print version' | tail -n 1)
- name: Output Version
  run: echo "${{ steps.version.outputs.snapshot }} :rocket:" >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
```

I would guess this would work if you used the $GITHUB_ENV mechanism